# How does function mapping between two spaces $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \xrightarrow[]{} \mathbb{R}^2$ work?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

This question will probably sound silly. In the mapping $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \xrightarrow[]{} \mathbb{R}^2$, with the function of $f(x) = x$, how does the dimension of the input equal the dimension of the output? As in, only one number, let's say 4, is mapped onto both $4 = x$ and $4 = y$, which are in $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, in the departure set, 4 *by itself* is also in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It seems like even though the sets are the same, the input has no descriptor of what the second dimension is. I guess this leads me to ask, what does "being in" $\mathbb{R}^2$ actually mean?

Comment: Slight error in the title; I meant to ask how mapping works between two identical subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and I just used $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an example.

Comment: Why do you think $f(x) = x$ is an example of an $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ map? It takes a single real number, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$ to another.

Comment: Unless you actually have in mind something like $(x, y) \mapsto (x,x)$

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis $x$ could denote an element of $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: But then you say "$4$ is mapped" which only makes sense if $x$ is a real number.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis I didn't say that. I'm not the OP

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting what "$f(x)=x$" means in this context. $x$ will represent an element of the domain (in tjis case, an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$), which is mapped to itself by $f$ (which is possible since the codomain is also $\mathbb{R}^2$). It's jist like writing $f((a,b)) = (a,b)$ (or $f(a,b)=(a,b)$), but using the symbol $x$ to represent an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{R}^2$, instead of using $(a,b)$ for that purpose.

Comment: “*I guess this leads me to ask, what does "being in" $\mathbb{R}^2$ actually mean?*” simply means an ordered pair of real numbers (i.e. something like (3,5) or (2.5,1)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to start, $4\notin\mathbb{R^2}$. Keep in mind that $\mathbb{R^2} = \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, and the cross product by definition only contains ordered pairs. So when you say "$4$ *by itself*  is also in $\mathbb{R^2}$", it is not entirely clear what element $4$ you are referring to.

Basically, when you write $f\colon\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $f(x) = x$, you have to keep in mind that for any $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$, $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, and this identity function $f$ maps these ordered tuples to themselves.